# GitHub limit for SSH deploy keys

Tags: github, ssh-keys

Is there any GitHub SSH Deploy key limit. Let's say I would need 2000 or even 4000 deploy keys added to the git repository. Is that possible or will I hit the limit at some point?

The reason for this is that we would have 4000 devices that would need to be provisioned. And we want to have control which device can access repository and if necessary disable it. Another option is indeed access tokens, but as far I understand they are linked to the account, not repository.

https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/

And that would also mean that we would need to manage the permissions separately to which repository they have access to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why would you need up to **4000** deploy keys? This is a pretty large number and I think you should explain why you need such a large amount of deploy keys for one single repository.

However: I contacted the GitHub support, after I couldn't find anything about this in the GitHub documentation and got the following response:

> I don't believe we have a fixed limit on SSH keys or deploy keys
> although as the settings pages weren't designed with this sort of
> usage in mind, I think it would be rather difficult to manage.
>
> When someone needs to control access to such a large number of
> machines, we'd usually recommend creating personal [access
> tokens](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization) instead,
> as these can be automated and will provide similar access. If
> the huge number of keys was necessary and causing problems, we'd do
> our best to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also sent an email to GitHub regarding the issue, but did not receive a response. The reason for this is that we would have 4000 devices that would need to be provisioned. And we want have control which device can access repository and if necessary disable it. Another option is indeed access tokens, but as far I understand they are linked to the account, not repository.