# How to setup ssh keys to acces github from one machine under different users

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu server with two users

```
root #root account of the system
myuser #user added to sudo group
```

Under root user I generated ssh keys which was added into. ssh directory

```
/root/.ssh 
         |__ id_rsa
         |__ id_rsa.pub
```

After it i run ssh-agent under the same root user

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Than added my private key to it

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

It was properly added than i added my public key to github repo.

After it i switched to my sudo user copied `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to my sudo user home directory 
`/home/myuser/.ssh/` and tried to access repo which was configured under root account and system prompt me that i hasn't access to it. I didnt understand why so. Can anyone guide me to properly setup access to github repo by the same private keys by two system users

Comment: You could copy the `id_rsa` or connect use the key of `root` and put that key on the server too.

Comment: @dan1st i did so i forget to mention about it. I edited myquestion

Comment: Did you also copy the `id_rsa.pub`? Have you updated the permissions of these files?

Comment: @dan1st yep i added id_rsa.pub too. Permissions of files under sudo user ?

Comment: Yes, do other users have permission to view the files? Is the root user owner of the files?

Comment: @dan1st i checked ownership and root is their owner and any other user have not access to rwx private key

Comment: @dan1st should i switch owner of private and pub key to sudo user ?

Comment: The root user should be the owner of the files and he should have `rw` permissions. The group and others shouldn't have `w` permissions on the public key and no permissions on the private key.

Comment: @dan1st i did like you said `-rw------- 1 root root id_git_keys -rw-r--r-- 1 root root id_git_keys.pub`

Comment: Oh, it is not actually named `id_rsa`?

Comment: @dan1st what is my next step

Comment: I think it tries to use `id_rsa` and not `id_git_keys`...

Comment: @dan1st no it's but i can rename them. But files have the same names under root and sudo user

Comment: In any way I would rather use the existing keys of the root user to connect to github (You'll need to upload them there before) than using the same keys.

Comment: @dan1st after correcting permissions i tried `ssh -T git@github.com` system prompt me `permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: @dan1st what do you mean by uploading them. Where and what i should upload ?

Comment: Eather the user has no permission to the public key or the public key is not (or not correctly) uploaded to github.

Comment: Paste the public key to the SSH Keys section in you account settings on github.

Comment: @dan1st public key correctly added because i can connect to git repo from root. Maybe pub key under sudo user should be owned by user itself ?

Comment: @dan1st public key as i said before added to git repo and i can connect to it under root user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if possible, don't generate or do anything as root. root should be for system tasks only.

Second, if you add a passphrase-protected SSH key to an ssh-gent running as root, the user might not have access to said agent once you are using that same SSH key with `sudo user`.
Try and run the `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` with the `sudo user` in order to run an agent as `user`.

But more generally, that all sequence should be done as the one local account `user` directly.
Copying *private* SSH keys around is not a good practice.

> I have one account and want to set it up to use the same github account under two linux users

Then:

- under local account user `user1`, generate an ssh key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
  ```

(defaults to `~user1/.ssh/id_rsa/id_rsa.pub`)

- under local account user `user2`, generate an ssh key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
  ```

(defaults to `~user2/.ssh/id_rsa/id_rsa.pub`)

Add *both* SSH public keys to your one unique GitHub account: see "[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)".
You can add as many key you want.

You will then be able to authenticate as that GitHub account from your local `user1` or `user2`, each one using their own SSH keys (no need to share *private* SSH keys across local accounts).

No need for a `~/.ssh/config` in that case.

Comment: Thank you for good advice about using root. How i can check that ssh key was generated with passphrase ?

Comment: Do you still have the command you used to generate those SSH keys? A simpler approach, for testing, would be to generate ones as user directly, without passphrase: `sudo user ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM`

Comment: Why you said that 'Copying private ssh keys around is not good practice'  as i understand in github i can add only one ssh pub key

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер You can generate as many ssh keys as you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066973/6309

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер I have edited the answer to illustrate how. Key point: forget root. You don't need root. I show how those "aliases" are used.

Comment: You gived me good advices about root using but i understand you didn't understand me properly. I haven't multiple github accounts i have one account and want to set it up to use the same github account under two linux users

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер I have rewritten the answer to address your setup (two local account, one Github remote account)

Comment: So easy solution. Complexity in my case was took place because i was thinking that in github can be added only one ssh private key. Thank you for your time spending i will upvote your answer

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер Thank you. Not only can you add more than one, but... there is *no* actual limit to the number of SSH keys you can add!! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552578/6309.

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by following steps. 
       •

- Deleted all git ssh keys under root 
           user as Vonc adviced
- Than generated new ssh key pair under sudo user.  Than added it to ssh-agent and added pub key to github account
- Than repeted all steps from previous step

Now I have two sudo user on my server each of this user have their ssh key pairs in their `/home/{USER}/.ssh` directories and pub keys of each Linux user added to github account.  And it's work fine.  Thank you for everyone who was helped to find solution

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way is to create ssh configuration file

#### Create an SSH config file

> When you have multiple identity files, create an SSH config file mechanism to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct an SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName github.com 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName github.com 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName github.com 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

#### Important:

Don't forget to load the keys to your GitHub account.

Comment: As i understand the important thing in ssh config is `alias` i have several ssh key pairs. First for accessing my server and second is ssh keys for accessing github. How i should configure alliases for this mentioned about entities ?